# Populate Div from Left to Right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that populates a div based on the number of my data and here is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      width: 40%;
      height: 180px;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    .container {
      padding: 2px 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onLoad="LoadAllData()">

  <div id="maincontainer" class="maincontainer">
  </div>

  <script>
    function LoadAllData() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(GenerateMainTable).getData();
    }

    function GenerateMainTable(data) {
      var createcard = document.getElementById("maincontainer");

      for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

        var imagelink = data[i][0]
        //alert(data[i][0]);
        createcard.innerHTML += '<div class="container">' +
          '<div class="card">' +
          imagelink +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

This code is working and it creates a div all the way down my question is how can i populate the div from left to right and so on. like this one

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by left-to-right?

Comment: Please explain 'left to right'?

Comment: You can add CSS property float:left to the container div or the card div

Comment: I mean instead populating the div all the way down it will start from left to right like card style something like that.

Comment: @paulpagente try my answer it will solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
    .card {
          box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          transition: 0.3s;
          width: 40%;
          height: 180px;
          float:left;
          margin: 2px; //For Adding space between divs
        }

        .card:hover {
          box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .container {
          padding: 2px 16px;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CSS` style for this -

```
  .yourPopulatedDiv{
     display:inline-block;
     float:left;
  }
```

Try this style in your `poppulated div` it may solve your issue.

in your case -

```
.card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      width: 40%;
      height: 180px;
      display:inline-block;
      float:left;
      margin-left:10px;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code. can you please create space between divs?

Comment: @paulpagente I have updated my code for you. Check it I have used `margin-left:10px` for space if you want you can use `%` as well in it. if its useful mark as answer, ty..!

Comment: tysm sir :) plus 1

Answer (score 1):

Take your container div outside of the loop.

```
'<div class="container">'
```

Then add css class for the container like

```
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Your function would look like

```
function GenerateMainTable(data) {
  var createcard = document.getElementById("maincontainer");
  createcard.innerHTML += '<div class="container">' 

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

    var imagelink = data[i][0]
    createcard.innerHTML += '<div class="card">' + imagelink + '</div>';

  }
  createcard.innerHTML += '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, are you looking to show you div from left to right on a single line as per the width of it's parent. If yes, then please try floating the child elements to "float: left" and with:100%. Remember to give a fixed width to the parent.

Regards,
Sijo Jose